# Короткий вариант функции

Tags: javascript

```
function correctPin (pin) {

if (!isNaN(pin) && Number.isInteger(pin) && pin.toString().length == 4 || pin.toString().length == 6) {
return true
} else {
return false
}
}
console.log(correctPin (2323));
```

Как написать более короткий вариант данной функции?

Comment: `isInteger` уже проверяет на `NaN` - предварительно не надо проверять

Comment: Отрицательный пин может быть признан правильным: `-123`.

Comment: Как быть с пином `0123`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может так короче?)
И ещё у вас была ошибка, что если пинкод имеет ровно 6 чисел то он проходит дпльше и не проверялся на isInteger ^-^

```js
function correctPin(pin) {
  return Number.isInteger(pin) && (pin.toString().length == 4 || pin.toString().length == 6) ? true : false
}
console.log(2323, correctPin(2323));

console.log(23223, correctPin(23223));

console.log('2323', correctPin('2323'));

console.log('22s323', correctPin('22s323'));
```

Comment: Какой смысл в конструкции `? true : false`?

Comment: `-123` пройдёт все тесты. Но это не пин.

Answer (score 0):

Начнём с того что `pin` не может быть числом. `'0123'` совершенно корректный пин, но его нельзя представить в виде числа. Даже если вы скажете что нули можно добавить слева если пин короткий, это не решит проблему: тогда вы не различите пины `'000123'` и `'0123'`.

Работать надо со строками из цифр длиной четыре или шесть. Регулярное выражение подходит идеально:

```
function correctPin(pin) {
    return /^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test(pin);
}

for (const s of ['0123', '000123', '123', '12345', '1234567', '12b3']) {
    console.log(s, correctPin(s));
}
```

> ```
> $ node correctPin.js
> 0123 true
> 000123 true
> 123 false
> 12345 false
> 1234567 false
> 12b3 false
> ```